# A Magento store runs better in a CPU or Memory optimized server?

Tags: magento2, performance, server-setup

I'm preparing my server, I have to choose a performance plan, independent of the hosting provider, which plan makes more sense to a Magento 2 store?

**General Purpose**

High-performance virtual machines with a good balance of memory and dedicated hyper-threads from best in class Intel processors. A great choice for a wide range of mainstream, production workloads, like web app hosting, e-commerce sites, medium-sized databases, and enterprise applications.

**CPU-Optimized**

Compute-optimized virtual machines with dedicated hyper-threads from best in class Intel processors. Best for CPU-intensive applications like CI/CD, video encoding and transcoding, machine learning, ad serving, batch processing, and active front-end web and application servers.

**Memory-Optimized**

Memory-rich virtual machines with 8GB of RAM per vCPU and dedicated hyper-threads from best-in-class Intel processors. Ideal for RAM-intensive applications like high-performance databases, web scale in-memory caches, and real-time big data processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 is complex PHP application and almost always CPU bounded.

So, CPU-Optimized will work better here.

See example CPU usage on Home Page (blue line - average is ~ 80%)
[image]